# Centering a WRAP_CONTENT

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

Currently I have a view within another view (its an ad) but because I am using MATCH_PARENT the width is the entire screen length when I only want it to be the ad size. Now WRAP_CONTENT fixes the problem but how do I centre the view on the bottom of the screen now? I was using the following code...

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setHorizontalGravity(Gravity.CENTER);    //Place centre
ll.setVerticalGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);  //place bottom
mobfoxView = new MobFoxView(this, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", true, true);
mobfoxView.setBannerListener(this);
mobfoxView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
ll.addView(mobfoxView);
this.addContentView(ll, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

problem is that it wont centre anymore because of the WRAP_CONTENT. How do I get this to work so the layout is centred at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: You should replace your hex numbers with their corresponding constants for nice code BTW.

Comment: yeah I was going to do that but what class are they held in? EDIT never mind i found that it was Gravity but the problem in the code remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these edits:

```
ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
mobfoxView = new MobFoxView(this, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", true, true);
mobfoxView.setBannerListener(this);
mobfoxView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
ll.addView(mobfoxView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
this.addContentView(ll, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

In this way if ll is appended at the end of the tree it will fill everything and position on the bottom.

Comment: Tried that one before, problem with using the FILL_PARENT is that is "fills" that entire axis with the view and the problem with WRAP_CONTENT is it doesnt know where the centre is

Comment: Can you show me your xml? Btw I said FILL_PARENT to the vertical and not horizontal layout!

Comment: either way the problem is still the same, I dont use any XML is all code and its all above

Comment: Are you sure your new LayoutParams are `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`?

Comment: import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams; - so seems so lol

Comment: also I have tried this.addContentView(ll, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); and the reverse. The first makes the ad on the top centre and the second is bottom centre but its still clickable for the whole screen length

Comment: i am still not desparate but i might postpone all this until tomoro .. it is 2:30 am here !! Anyway try `ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);`

Comment: awesome I did change a little part in the first parameters, seems the WRAP_CONTENT wasnt working quite right so I manually defined it to be 400.